# Why is the div not updated, after the .css() method is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I finish dragging a div, I would like to put it back to its previous location, stored in data-x, data-y. But jQuery does not modify `$(".current")` in the "up" method :

- the data-x,data-y is correctly stored,
- the values stored are showing correctly with oX,oY,
- but the final values are always the ones from mousemove, even though the "up" method is called after mousemove.

The code :

```
$(window).on('mouseup', function(){
    if (dragDown){
        var oX = $(".current").attr("data-X");
        var oY = $(".current").attr("data-Y");
        console.log("oXY: "+oX+", "+oY); //<--- works fine
        $(".current").css({"top":oY, "left":oX}); //<--- does not work

        console.log("up: "+$(".current").css("top")+", "+$(".current").css("left"));
    }
    dragDown = false;
});
$(".draggable").on('mousemove', function(e){ //<--- .draggable
    if (dragDown){
        //...
        console.log("move: "+$(".current").css("top")+", "+$(".current").css("left"));
        $(".current").css({"top":resultY, "left":resultX}); //<---works fine   
    }
});


<div id="containerDrag">
    <div id="drag" class="draggable current">
    </div>
</div>
```

So after a mouseup, the div stays where it is, instead of going back to the values stored in data-x, data-y.

The output is :

```
move: 16.6875px, 128px
move: 15.6875px, 130px
move: 15.6875px, 131px
oXY: 81, 21.6875
up: 15.6875px, 132px
```

and the output in the element console : the values data and style should be the same :

[image]

Comment: Where do you set the "dragDown" variable to true?

Comment: What happens if you step into the call to `css`? Does it get set temporarily? Is it possible it's getting set to your value then back to something else?

Comment: Did you set the position?? Because top,left,etc, only works with positioned element I believe

Comment: maybe using the .data instead of .attr

Comment: @StealthSpoder It says in the question it gets the values from the data attribute fine.

Comment: And how does the data attributes get set, how is that element draggable, are you using jQuery UI? There's information missing here ?

Comment: im getting it to work with:
 
        $(".current").css("top", oY + "px");
 $(".current").css("left", oX + "px");
but not with:

        $(".current").css({"top":oY, "left":oX});

check out fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rf5up5fr/42/

Comment: This example should be modified so that it is a complete working example. In order to get it working, we need to make a lot of modifications, such as figuring out where to set 'dragDown' to true, there are no 'data-X' or 'data-Y' attributes, result-X and result-Y are not set, etc.

Comment: sorry fiddle is now  https://jsfiddle.net/rf5up5fr/45/

Comment: @StealthSpoder Yes great StealthSpoder, it works fine with +"px" thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a drag and drop tutorial at w3schools.com that may save you some work: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I have your answer:

```
$(".current").css({"top":oX + "px" , "left":oY + "px"});
```

I am sorry I cant tell you why, in your other function the variables must be slightly different?

https://jsfiddle.net/rf5up5fr/52/